# How to sort array element using PHP

Tags: php

How to sort the below array in PHP

```
Array
(
    [server1] => Array
        (
            [hid] => A201
            [rack] => A1
            [hname] => server1
            [error] => 45
        )

    [server2] => Array
        (
            [hid] => A110
            [rack] => A2
            [hname] => server2
            [error] => 43
        )

    [server3] => Array
        (
            [[hid] => A301
            [rack] => A3
            [hname] => server3
            [error] => 57
        )
```

Output required:

```
[server3] => Array
        (
            [[hid] => A301
            [rack] => A3
            [hname] => server3
            [error] => 57
         )

[server1] => Array
        (
            [hid] => A201
            [rack] => A1
            [hname] => server1
            [error] => 45
        )

[server2] => Array
        (
            [hid] => A110
            [rack] => A2
            [hname] => server2
            [error] => 43
        )
```

Comment: Did you try any of the sort functions?

Comment: Take a look at the answer shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/how-to-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value?rq=1